# UIView retainCount is 0, but the memory isn't released

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, uikit

I'm developing an app for iOS and I'm running into issues with low memory warnings.

My app is loading a large view with lots of subviews upon tapping a button. The memory usage grows and that's pretty understandable (from 30 Mb to 80Mb). However when user selects another menu item - this view is released, but! the amount of memory used by the app doesn't reduce any. I use the following code to release the view:

```
storeView.hidden = YES;
NSLog(@"%d", [storeView retainCount]);
[storeView removeFromSuperview];
storeView = nil;
```

NSLog in the second line prints: 1, so after the release it should be deallocated. My implementation of -(void) dealloc; does get called (and I call [super dealloc]; on the last line of it). Yet after that I'm still have low memory warnings.

Instruments found only a couple of leaked NSStrings which couldn't possible cause memory warnings.

Could you please give any advice?

Comment: Forget about retainCount property, never use it

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks. Any other suggestion? The object does get deallocated - its dealloc method was called. Yet memory isn't released.

Comment: The memory is consumed not by the view itself, but by the objects the view is holding. When your `dealloc` gets called, see if you are releasing the objects referenced by the view. Run with a memory profiler, and see where does the memory go.

Comment: See [When to use -retainCount?](http://whentouseretaincount.com).

Comment: Note that `retainCount` can, by definition, never return 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A release call lowers the retain count, if the retain count is 0 it MIGHT be cleared but it doesn't have to be. When the retain count is zero and you try to access a variable, it might still work, it might not work. You can't count on it either way.

Comment: May be I should have better named my question. The point is that the memory usage doesn't reduce even after the dealloc method of a corresponding view was called.

Comment: Then it is not this view that is causing the memory warning.